# Possible to do a lookup on a db table within a SSRS Expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to make a lookup within a SSRS expression, is that possible ?

The idea behind that: for a check report I have to decide if a value on the report is ok,
if not it should be shown with a red background color. However instead of keeping the values that are ok in the expression I would like to use lookup in a sql table where these values are centrally stored.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through custom code or assemblies, but I'd look for a way to do it in the data source query instead. Is your data source the same SQL database?

Comment: Yes it is, I had a look at R2 and I think this will fix my problem. Custom code is a bit to much trouble to maintain later on I feel.

Answer (score 0):

In Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS for SQL Server 2008R2, you can use the Lookup() function:

```
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

[MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also, a couple of sites with examples I found helpful:

http://sqlcircuit.blogspot.com/2012/03/ssrs-2008-r2-lookup-how-to-use-multiple.html#!/2012/03/ssrs-2008-r2-lookup-how-to-use-multiple.html

and

http://blog.jontav.com/post/23229005764/ssrs-lookup

**Be sure to use shared datasets!**